# Add subview to UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, addsubview

I'm trying to add subviews to a `UIButton`. This is working fine right now. But the button isn't clickable anymore as soon as I add the subviews.

I use the following code:

```objectivec
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(column*100+24, row*80+10, 64, 64);
[button addSubview:asyncImage];
[button addSubview:price];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The button works again if I remove the 2 `addSubview:` methods. If anyone knows how to fix this it would be great!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I found a quick solutions. I needed to set the `asyncImageView` to the following:

```objectivec
asyncImage.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
asyncImage.exclusiveTouch = NO;
```

After this, it worked!

Comment: Will answer my questions in 2 days when possible

Comment: I was thinking the opposite regarding the 'userInteractionEnabled' property, I thought the setting it to "YES" should actually catch click event on the subview of the button.

GREAT ANSWER!

Comment: Simply setting `userInteractionEnabled = false` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

try:

`[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

instead of:

`[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonControlType];`

Comment: That doesn't work, it gives me an error, doesn't recognize UIButtonControlType

Comment: oh, then try setting user interaction to enabled, like this [YOUR BUTTON setUserInteractionEnabled://bool, for you its YES

Comment: I tried that for the 2 subviews (price and asyncImage) and for the button. Bit didn't made any difference...

Answer (score 2):

The important thing here is to make sure that `userInteractionEnabled` will be set to `NO`. Fortunately it works immediately for `UIImageView` and `UILabel` (maybe for other subclasses of a `UIView` but those are the most popular subviews added to button) because by default for this classes it is set to `NO` by default. Unfortunately it is set to `YES` in `UIView` so make sure to change it in that case. Messing around with any other flags shouldn't be necessary. The nature of problem is that many people do not know that default value of this flag is different in subclasses.

Comment: @benhi, cool. If you want me to help - more details will be helpful :P

Comment: Julian 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *popular;

popular = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, popular.frame.size.width, popular.frame.size.height)];

label.text = @"ButtonTitle"; 

label.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; 

label.userInteractionEnabled = NO; 

[popular addSubview:label];

Comment: so it doesn't detect the touches or what doesn't work?

Comment: the label doesn't appear

Comment: what frames do you give it, it might be that the width and height is 0? are you sure that at that time the button is already initialised? Btw the not showing label is a bit offtopic here ;) as the problem here was that the added subview disabled a touches

Comment: the button is already initialised and I see it in my device, so the the width and height isn't 0...

Comment: I Create the button in the storyboard

Comment: You said that label is bot appearing and now it is so what is the truth :-P?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put:

```
[asyncImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: have you tried also with the other view? [price setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

Answer (score 1):

in the same sitiation i make this action:
inherit from UIButton and add all labels and imageview's of button to self, finally put new button to view as last subview and add targets of self button to this last button(also set backgroundColor to clearColor for transparent). now it will be clickable and works fine.

Comment: I get somehow the idea, but don't exactly know what I need to do. Do you have a short example? Thnx!

Comment: I mainly don't understand what you mean with making the action inherit from UIButton, and setting it to self. If I do self.button it gives me an error. Thnx!

Comment: Wow, OK! Gonna try that! Thnx

Answer (score 1):

I added a label to the subview button.
For a very long time I was looking for why my text in the button is not clickable. Solution in this thread:

```
myLable.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, test that is you have your UIButton blocked

```
uibtn.userInteractionEnabled = false
uibtn.exclusiveTouch = false
```