# Button not clickable after adding as a subview to a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uibutton

I have created a class called `UICustomButton`, which is a subclass of `UIView`. I added a `UIButton` to `UIView` as a `subview` as shown in my code below:

```
-(id)initWithButtonType:(NSString *)type
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.customButton = [self setupButtonWithTitle:type andFrame:frame];
        [self addSubview:self.customButton];
        self.customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }
    return self;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that although the button appears, they are not clickable. Is there something wrong with the way I am adding the buttons to the `UIView`?

[image]

EDIT: To add on, I am using this custom button class instance to a cell:

```
UICustomButton *customButton = [[UICustomButton alloc]initWithFrame:someFrame];
[cell.contentView addSubView:customButton];
```

Comment: What does `setupButtonWithTitle:andFrame:` do? Also, you need to make sure that if the code for `initWithButtonType:` references `self` to add a selector `buttonPressed`, that the `buttonPressed` method is indeed implemented in the same class.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675233/addsubview-to-uibutton

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check the frame of your `UICustomButton` object, and if `self.customButton` is out of its `superView`.

Comment: Yup my superview was not being set up properly. That was causing the problem. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: can you please tell me how to check frame of UIButton and if the button is out of its superView?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the frame of the subview is within the frame of its superview. I encountered the issue twice and both times the frame of the subview was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if all properties `userInteractionEnabled` are on:

1. Check that property for `UITableView` where your cells with this view are displayed
2. Check that property for `UITableViewCell` where you add this view as subview
3. Check that property for `UICustomButton`
4. Check that property for `customButton` in `-(id)initWithButtonType:(NSString *)type`

Answer (score 0):

My button was not working because i had two views in each other. The first view, as you can see, has a width and heigth of 0 pixels. I've made this view the same size as view2 and then my button was clickable.

```
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(325, 346, 0, 0)];
    view1.alpha = 0.90;

    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 450, 150)];
    [view2.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(addClosedToCollection) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 300, 32)];
    [btn setTitle:@"i'm a button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [view2 addSubview:btn];
    [view1 addSubview:view2];
```

i hope i've helped somebody out :)

Answer (score 0):

Your outer view probably has a height of 0. Add constraints that makes it the same height as (or higher than) the subviews, or create it with a frame that is large enough.

Answer (score -1):

try putting this after the if statement:

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```